# Linked reports in SSRS

Tags: ssrs

Can some one help me how to find out Original report of a Linked report in SSRS.

We tried by editing the permissions on SSRS console and report permissions but no luck.

Thanks,
Venkat Kokulla

Answer (score 1):

I believe the below should give you what you are looking for?

In the `ReportServer` database:

```
SELECT link.Name AS LinkName, link.Path AS LinkPath, 
source.name AS OrginalReport, source.Path AS OrginalReportPath 
FROM dbo.Catalog link INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog AS source ON link.LinkSourceID=source.ItemID
```